# .NET Path Combine

Tags: .net

I have an issue path combine.

```
...
repository.ConfigDir = Path.Combine(repository.Dir, @"\Config");
repository.CredFile = Path.Combine(repository.ConfigDir, @"\Credentials.xml");

System.out.println(repository.ConfigDir);
System.out.println(repository.CredFile);
```

Output:

```
"C:\Users\username\Documents\Config"

"\\Credentials.xml"
```

Why my first part of the path is missing in `CredFile`?

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like Java code...

Answer (score 4):

One of the main points in using `Path.Combine()` is to avoid having to include leading and trailing "\" or "/" separators. Remove the "\" from your path strings (these are essentially redirecting the path to the root anyway) and it will work as you expect.